# How to create Language Pack/Dictionary for Keyboard auto correct

Tags: languages, localization, locale

Is there a way to create new language pack for android? I would like to use my local language words, but i wouldnt want to add them in the 'English' pack, because they are words/phrases in my country and it would make my english pack messy.

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?